# Need help proving indexed family of sets questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Need to prove the equality:
$$
(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i)-(\bigcup_{j\in J} B_j)=\bigcup_{i\in I}(\bigcap_{j\in J}[A_i-B_j])
$$

Any ideas on how to start? Thank you

Comment: this question is unclear as it is phrased. Please use $$ signs to edit.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. Just started using LATEX. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}(\bigcap_{j\in J}[A_i-B_j])=\bigcup_{i\in I}(\bigcap_{j\in J}[A_i \cap B_j^c])=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \cap(\bigcap_{j\in J} B_j^c)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\left[A_i -(\bigcup_{j\in J}B_j)\right]$$
$$=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i -(\bigcup_{j\in J}B_j)$$

Edit (proof second to third equality):

$$\bigcap_{j\in J}[A_i \cap B_j^c]=A_i \cap(\bigcap_{j\in J} B_j^c)$$
$$x \in \bigcap_{j\in J}[A_i \cap B_j^c] \iff x \in A_i \cap B_j^c,  \forall j \in J  \iff x \in A_i  \wedge x \in B_j^c,  \forall j \in J$$ 
$$\iff x \in A_i  \wedge x \in (\bigcap_{j\in J} B_j^c) \iff x \in A_i \cap(\bigcap_{j\in J} B_j^c) $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how did you get from the second expression to the third? Is there a theorem for the equality?

Comment: Edited for the explanation. Hope it helps